# interpreting results of ls-l

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, python, ls, chmod

I'm having trouble interpreting the results of ls -l in my directory:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root      37114 Jul 24 02:13  madison_events.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root     131355 Jul 24 16:00  milwaukee_events.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root      67570 Jul 26 19:42  minneapolis_events.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root     402115 Jul 24 16:33  nashville_events.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root      70429 Jul 24 16:46  neworleans_events.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   546936 Jul 27 02:15  nyc_events.json
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   root      58037 Jul 24 16:50  seattle_events.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   141303 Jul 27 01:04  sf_events.json
```

I've been noticing that my python script can write to files listed `ubuntu` (nyc_events.josn and sf_events.json) but it cannot write to those listed root (seattle_events.json, nashville_events.json, etc).

What does root vs. ubuntu mean in this case, and how can I get the files that read 'root' to read 'ubuntu'?  I've also noticed that in filezilla, the root files have a numeric value of `664`, while the ubuntu files have a value of `775`.

In short, I want to be able to write to all of these files. Thanks.

Comment: You may find the man page for ls to be enlightneing.  `man ls`

Comment: @user10489 You will notice that the manual for `ls` does not mention how to change ownership and permissions on files.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the files are owned by root (and group root too).  This is because at some point you have run the script that generates them as root.  Don't do that, only use root for systems administration tasks that require root permissions.   The ownership can be fixed with `chown`.

The root-owned files also have execute permissions, probably because root's `umask` sets the execute bit on new files by default.   `.json` files typically don't need to be executable (because they're just json data, not a script), so you should fix that with `chmod`.

To fix the ownership and permissions, `cd` to the directory that contains the files and:

```
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu *.json
sudo chmod 644 *.json
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being the files which are listed as `root` are owned by `root` user and hence cannot be altered by any other user like `ubuntu` in your case.
For your program to be able to write to the files listed as `root` you will have to change the ownership of those files using `chown` command.
Steps:

1. Login as `root` user.
2. `cd` to the folder which contains your files
3. `chown ubuntu:ubuntu *.json`

OR just execute:

1. `cd <to the directory>; sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu *.json`

Hope this helps!